# How to import data from CSV file to MySql table only for selected columns and CSV has both values enclosed with " " and not enclosed with " "

Tags: mysql, database, csv

I have tried using this commands

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/cs/Documents/abc.csv' 
INTO TABLE whatsappmessages 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
IGNORE 1 ROWS  
(number,@Number,message,@Message) 
set createdtime=now();
```

It is inserting number column value correctly , But in message column few data which are enclosed with ""(double quotes) and after the comma(,) string is taking(ie: logo and details. Click https://xxxx.co/xyzop now!) and inserting not the full value , but without double quotes empty string is inserting(ie: second line) .

**This is the CSV file content i have**

```
1111111111,"MARKET YOUR STORE! Customize xxxxxx latest emailer featuring aaaa cccc with your store name, logo and details. Click https://xxxx.co/xyzop now!"
2222222222,MARKET YOUR STORE! By sharing xxxxxx stunning collection featuring aaaa cccc with your consumer database. Click https://xxxx.co/xyzop now!
2222222222,"MARKET YOUR STORE! Customize xxxxxx latest emailer featuring aaaa cccc with your store name, logo and details. Click https://xxxx.co/xyzop now!"
3333333333,MARKET YOUR STORE! By sharing xxxxxx stunning collection featuring aaaa cccc with your consumer database. Click https://xxxx.co/xyzop now!
```

***Anyone knows how to solve this please help me out, Thanks!***

Comment: I don't know how to do it with pure mySQL, but if you are willing to throw a programming language into the mix (i.e. PHP), you could first parse the string manually and then insert that using the built in interfaces.

Comment: #1. Your CSV contains the data for 2 columns only whereas the columns list contains 4 columns. Use `(number,message)`. #2. Add `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` for FIELDS. #3. Make your `createdtime` auto-utilized, and remove SET clause.

Comment: Thanks @Akina ,Yes i tried as you said but one row is inserting . 1111111111 to number column and rest of all the things inserting into message column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/cs/Documents/abc.csv' 
  INTO TABLE whatsappmessages FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
  IGNORE 1 ROWS (number, message) 
set 
  createdtime = now();
```

Comment: This query is working fine.